# Add vertical line as a divider in tabbar as a divider

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform, tabbar

I have a tab bar and i need to put a vertical line as a divider between tabs, how to do that?
this how i used my tabbar:

```
new TabBar(
                    unselectedLabelColor: Color.fromRGBO(119, 119, 119, 1),
                    labelColor: Colors.black,
                    controller: controller,
                    tabs: <Tab>[
                      new Tab(text: "Girls"),
                      new Tab(text: "Hero"),
                      new Tab(text: "Open"),
                    ]),
```

and I need it to be like this:

[image]

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: No I didn't find any solution

Comment: I have found the solution. Please check in answers

Answer (score 9):

**Finally It worked for me**

```
TabBar(
    tabs: [
        _individualTab('assets/icons/bottom_nav/Home.png'),
        _individualTab('assets/icons/bottom_nav/Guys.png'),
        _individualTab('assets/icons/bottom_nav/Notes.png'),
        Tab(
            icon: ImageIcon(
                AssetImage('assets/icons/bottom_nav/Email.png')
            ),
        ),
    ],
    labelColor: STColors.PRIMARY_COLOR,
    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
    indicatorColor: Colors.white,
    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
    labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
),
```

**Individual Tab Function**

```
Widget _individualTab(String imagePath) {
    return Container(
        height: 50 + MediaQuery
          .of(context)
          .padding
          .bottom,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration:  BoxDecoration(border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: STColors.LIGHT_BORDER, width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid))),
        child: Tab(
            icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage(imagePath)),
        ),
    );
}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

To achieve small size separator you can use this.

```
Widget _individualTab(String imagePath) {
return Container(
  height: 50,
  width: double.infinity,
  decoration:  BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: STColors.LIGHT_BORDER,
        width: 0,
        style: BorderStyle.solid),
    ),
  ),
  child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
    Center(
        child: Tab(
          icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage(imagePath)),
        ),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: Container(
        color: STColors.appBlackMedium,
        width: 1,
        height: 25,
      ),
    )
  ],)
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
indicator: BoxDecoration(
  border: Border(
    left: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey), // provides to left side
    right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey), // for right side
  ),
),
```

---

Your solution:

```
new TabBar(
  indicator: BoxDecoration(border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange))),
  unselectedLabelColor: Color.fromRGBO(119, 119, 119, 1),
  labelColor: Colors.black,
  controller: controller,
  tabs: <Tab>[
    new Tab(text: "Girls"),
    new Tab(text: "Hero"),
    new Tab(text: "Open"),
  ]),
```

Comment: No...It just give border to the tabs that is selected. and it is not what I actually need. it need to have vertical line between each tabs even a tab is not selected. exactly like the one we have VerticalDivider() but it is not working with tabbars.

Comment: has somebody found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the Header I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qczO.png)

Yea, so I added a var called rightDivider which lets you render divider but the last tab on my custom tab widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final bool rightDivider;

  TabWidget({
    required this.label,
    required this.rightDivider,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    height: 32 + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      decoration: (rightDivider)
          ? BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                right: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  width: 1,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid,
                ),
              ),
            )
          : null,
      child: Center(child: Text(label)),
    );
  }
}
```

And called this widget like this

```
TabBar(
    controller: _tabController,
    tabs: [
        TabWidget(
            label: 'Today',
            rightDivider: true,
        ),
        TabWidget(
            label: 'Calendar',
            rightDivider: true,
        ),
        TabWidget(
            label: 'Report',
            rightDivider: false,
        ),
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how I achieve this behavior...

```
HomeTab({required String title, bool isSeprator = true}) {
    return Tab(
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 20,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(title),
        ),
        decoration: isSeprator
            ? BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  left: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    width: 1,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : null,
      ),
    );
  }
```

`isSeparator` is to show separator or not ... because on the last index I am not showing...

Following is the list of `tabs` ...

```
List<Widget> _tabScroll() => [
        HomeTab(title: "Tab1"),
        HomeTab(title: "Tab2"),
        HomeTab(title: "Tab3", isSeparator: false),
      ];
```

and following is the most important `TabBar` Code...

```
         TabBar(
                labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0), //removing extra space 
                controller: _controller,
                isScrollable: true,
                indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3.0), //hight of indicator
                  insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0), //give some padding to reduce the size of indicator 
                ),
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                tabs: _tabScroll(), //list of tabs
              ),
```

The end result looks like this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Working solution is to create border for individual tabs. Tabs parameter actually accept other elements as a child. So you can use custom containers. That way you can control which side border you want to show (left, rigth or any side):

```
TabBar(
                            controller: _tabController,
                            indicator: BoxDecoration(
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  offset: Offset(0, 2.0),
                                )
                              ],
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            labelColor: Colors.red,
                            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
                            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
                            isScrollable: false,
                            tabs: [
                              Container(
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text('T1'),
                                  ),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(
                                      right: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        width: 2,
                                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )),
                              Container(
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text('T2'),
                                  ),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(
                                      right: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        width: 2,
                                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )),
                              Container(
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text('T3'),
                                  ),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(
                                      right: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        width: 2,
                                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )),
                              Tab(
                                text: 'T4',
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats how i have done this
I am using screenutils package from pub you can also use it

```
SizedBox(
          width: 342.w,
          height: 41.h,
          child: Material(
            
            color: const Color(0xffE2E2E2),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
              child: TabBar(
                   padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                   indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
               labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            
                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                        
                  // borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
                ),
                labelColor: Colors.black,
                unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xff999BA2),
                tabs: [
                  Container(
                    width: 1.sw,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      // color: Colors.black,
                      border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))
                    ),
                    child: Tab(
                      text: 'Call',
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 1.sw,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))
                    ),
                    child: Tab(
                      text: 'Missed Call',
                    ),
                    // child: Tab(text: 'Phone',),
                  ),
                  Container(
            
                    child: Tab(
                      text: 'No Call',
                    ),
                    // child: Tab(text: 'No Call'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYwKb.png)